# vs code intellisense results are just limited to 1

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Whenever I am writing the code in VS Code, then the IntelliSense is only showing one option. Doesn't matter which language I use, I am getting only one suggestion for every language. BTW I'm working with flutter. (See the mentioned images)

**Expected behavior**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDW86.png (I can't
add images because of the less reputation)

**Behaviour now**
Right now I can only see the very first option in IntelliSense. Maybe I have messed up my VS code settings but I'm not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem, and this worked for me. Literally just expanding the results to show more than one. Let me know if this was of help.

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_51#_intellisense

Answer (score 0):

You need to add extensions related to your working language.

[image]